# Send midi signal from c# to ableton

Tags: c#, midi, ableton-live

I'm trying to send a midi signal from my c# app to a track in Ableton Live.

I've tried both the Bass.net and midi-dot-net both with the same effect: No events arriving in Ableton. (I've got loopMidi installed and thats where I send my signals to.)

Strangely enough when I target my midi-keyboard it plays the stanard piano sound..

My code is 1-1 copy of the examples on the sites:

```
OutputDevice outputDevice = OutputDevice.InstalledDevices[0];
outputDevice.Open();
outputDevice.SendNoteOn(Channel.Channel1, Pitch.C4, 80);  // Middle C, velocity 80
outputDevice.SendPitchBend(Channel.Channel1, 7000);  // 8192 is centered, so 7000 is bent down
```

As I'm still quite to new to midi I think I'm still misunderstanding some basics here.. 
Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This kind of question has nothing to do with C#, everything to do with the app you're trying to automate.  Use the vendor's dedicated support channels to find help, starting page is here: http://www.ableton.com/community

Comment: From your post you seem to have proved that your app is sending midi out of the computer. So either you're sending the wrong midi commands to Abelton, or there is something not right in Abelton ? Check out the link Hans suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise using a utility such as MidiOx to see that MIDI signals are actually being sent as you suspect they are.

If that is working as expected, then you probably haven't configured Live's MIDI I/O correctly in the preferences. A nice way to test this is to enter MIDI mapping mode in live, then click on any clip in the session view. Have your program send MIDI data, and if Live can receive that data you will see it map a MIDI event to the clip in question.

Comment: @AyKarsi Can you send me a step by step guide on what you did. I manage to play the notes on the output but on Ableton or MidiOx I am not getting the notes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not sending MIDI to Ableton live but to a MIDI output port. What you need is to use a virtual MIDI port that you can send data to and it can present that data back to another application. The [MIDI Yoke](http://www.midiox.com/) application can do this.

Comment: Can you help me on to send the notes to the MIDI port? I am stuck. I am at the same stage as this guy